# Removing a git submodule without a path

Tags: git, git-submodules, gitpython

I somehow have a git submodule without a path, which I would like to remove.

Looking into the submodules of my codebase, there is some weird config:

```
[submodule "a/path"]
    path = a/path
    url = <the-git-url>
[submodule "a/path/"]
    url = <the-git-url>
```

Note the second submodule has a trailing "/" on the submodule header, no path variable, and points to the same git repo.

This has no bad effects (as far as I can tell) on our typical usage of the codebase and submodules. I only noticed it when GitPython threw an error trying to look at the submodules because of the lack of a path variable.

I want to remove the second submodule record (without a path), but all steps I can find for removing submodules just ends up removing the top one (e.g. `git rm a/path/`).

How can I remove it? Is it safe to just remove from .gitmodules?